# multi threading in a single JFrame

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I was trying trying to create two threads working each for its own panel in a single frame, I mean I was trying to change images concurrently in a single frame but in two different panels of same size in single frame.

I have done it for two different frames running their own images but I want to be happen this in a single frame in its own panels.

My coding was:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import org.omg.CORBA.Object;
import java.awt.*;

class subviewer1 extends JFrame implements Runnable{

    Thread t2 = new Thread();

    JFrame f1;
    //JLabel label;
    JPanel p1;
    ImageIcon icon; //= new ImageIcon("C:\\img.png");
        JLabel label = new JLabel(icon); 

    int imgPath = 1;

    public subviewer1(){        
        super();
        t2.start();
        /*
        f1 = new JFrame("PIC VIEWER");
        f1.setLayout(null);
        f1.setSize(500,500);
        f1.setLocation(0,0);        
        p1 = new JPanel();      
        while(true)
        {
            try {
            while (true) {          
                Thread.sleep(1000);                
                p1.setSize(500,500);
                p1.setLocation(0,0);                
                switch(imgPath)
                {
                    case 1:
                        //f1.remove(p1);
                        p1.remove(label);
                        p1.setVisible(false);
                        p1.removeAll();
                        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("C:\\img.png");
                        JLabel label = new JLabel(icon); 
                        p1.add(label);
                        p1.setVisible(true);
                        imgPath = 2;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        //f1.remove(p1);
                        p1.removeAll();
                        p1.setVisible(false);
                        ImageIcon icon1 = new ImageIcon("C:\\img1.png");
                        JLabel label1 = new JLabel(icon1);
                        p1.add(label1);
                        p1.setVisible(true);
                        imgPath = 3;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        //f1.remove(p1);
                        p1.removeAll();
                        p1.setVisible(false);
                        ImageIcon icon2 = new ImageIcon("C:\\img2.png");
                        JLabel label2 = new JLabel(icon2); 
                        p1.add(label2);
                        p1.setVisible(true);
                        imgPath = 4;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        //f1.remove(p1);
                        p1.setVisible(false);
                        p1.removeAll();
                        ImageIcon icon3 = new ImageIcon("C:\\img3.png");
                        JLabel label3 = new JLabel(icon3);    
                        p1.add(label3);
                        p1.setVisible(true);
                        imgPath = 1;
                        break;
                }                
                f1.add(p1);
                f1.setVisible(true);
                f1.setLayout(null);
                setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            }
            } catch (InterruptedException iex) {
                System.out.println(iex);
            }
        }
         //initComponents();         
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {     
        {           
            f1 = new JFrame("PIC VIEWER");
            //f1.setLayout(null);
            f1.setSize(500,500);
            f1.setLocation(0,0);
            p1 = new JPanel();          
            while(true)
            {
                try {
                while (true) {              
                    Thread.sleep(1000);                 
                    p1.setSize(250,500);
                    p1.setLocation(0,0);                    
                    switch(imgPath)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            //f1.remove(p1);
                            p1.remove(label);
                            p1.setVisible(false);
                            p1.removeAll();
                            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("C:\\img.png");
                            JLabel label = new JLabel(icon); 
                            p1.add(label);
                            p1.setVisible(true);
                            imgPath = 2;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            //f1.remove(p1);
                            p1.removeAll();
                            p1.setVisible(false);
                            ImageIcon icon1 = new ImageIcon("C:\\img1.png");
                            JLabel label1 = new JLabel(icon1);
                            p1.add(label1);
                            p1.setVisible(true);
                            imgPath = 3;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            //f1.remove(p1);
                            p1.removeAll();
                            p1.setVisible(false);
                            ImageIcon icon2 = new ImageIcon("C:\\img2.png");
                            JLabel label2 = new JLabel(icon2); 
                            p1.add(label2);
                            p1.setVisible(true);
                            imgPath = 4;
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            //f1.remove(p1);
                            p1.setVisible(false);
                            p1.removeAll();
                            ImageIcon icon3 = new ImageIcon("C:\\img3.png");
                            JLabel label3 = new JLabel(icon3);    
                            p1.add(label3);
                            p1.setVisible(true);
                            imgPath = 1;
                            break;
                    }                   
                    f1.add(p1);
                    f1.setVisible(true);
                    f1.setLayout(null);
                    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                }
                } catch (InterruptedException iex) {
                    System.out.println(iex);
                }
            }       
        }   
    }
}
```

and

```
class subviewer2 extends JFrame implements Runnable{

    Thread t1 = new Thread();   
    JFrame f1;
    //JLabel label;
    JPanel p2;  
    ImageIcon icon; //= new ImageIcon("C:\\img.png");   
        JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);    
    int imgPath = 1;

    public subviewer2(){        
        super();
        t1.start();
        /*
        f1 = new JFrame("PIC VIEWER");
        f1.setLayout(null);
        f1.setSize(500,500);
        f1.setLocation(0,0);        
        p1 = new JPanel();

        while(true)
        {
            try {
            while (true) {          
                Thread.sleep(1000);                
                p1.setSize(500,500);
                p1.setLocation(0,0);                
                switch(imgPath)
                {
                    case 1:
                        //f1.remove(p1);
                        p1.remove(label);
                        p1.setVisible(false);
                        p1.removeAll();
                        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("C:\\img4.png");
                        JLabel label = new JLabel(icon); 
                        p1.add(label);
                        p1.setVisible(true);
                        imgPath = 2;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        //f1.remove(p1);
                        p1.removeAll();
                        p1.setVisible(false);
                        ImageIcon icon1 = new ImageIcon("C:\\img5.png");
                        JLabel label1 = new JLabel(icon1);
                        p1.add(label1);
                        p1.setVisible(true);
                        imgPath = 3;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        //f1.remove(p1);
                        p1.removeAll();
                        p1.setVisible(false);
                        ImageIcon icon2 = new ImageIcon("C:\\img6.png");
                        JLabel label2 = new JLabel(icon2); 
                        p1.add(label2);
                        p1.setVisible(true);
                        imgPath = 4;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        //f1.remove(p1);
                        p1.setVisible(false);
                        p1.removeAll();
                        ImageIcon icon3 = new ImageIcon("C:\\img7.png");
                        JLabel label3 = new JLabel(icon3);    
                        p1.add(label3);
                        p1.setVisible(true);
                        imgPath = 1;
                        break;
                }                
                f1.add(p1);
                f1.setVisible(true);
                f1.setLayout(null);
                setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            }
            } catch (InterruptedException iex) {
                System.out.println(iex);
            }
        }
         //initComponents();        
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {     
        {

            f1 = new JFrame("PIC VIEWER");
        //  f1.setLayout(null);
            f1.setSize(500,500);
            f1.setLocation(0,0);            
            p2 = new JPanel();          
            while(true)
            {
                try {
                while (true) {              
                    Thread.sleep(1000);                 
                    p2.setSize(350,500);
                    p2.setLocation(250,0);                  
                    switch(imgPath)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            //f1.remove(p1);
                            p2.remove(label);
                            p2.setVisible(false);
                            p2.removeAll();
                            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("C:\\img4.png");
                            JLabel label = new JLabel(icon); 
                            p2.add(label);
                            p2.setVisible(true);
                            imgPath = 2;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            //f1.remove(p1);
                            p2.removeAll();
                            p2.setVisible(false);
                            ImageIcon icon1 = new ImageIcon("C:\\img5.png");
                            JLabel label1 = new JLabel(icon1);
                            p2.add(label1);
                            p2.setVisible(true);
                            imgPath = 3;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            //f1.remove(p1);
                            p2.removeAll();
                            p2.setVisible(false);
                            ImageIcon icon2 = new ImageIcon("C:\\img6.png");
                            JLabel label2 = new JLabel(icon2); 
                            p2.add(label2);
                            p2.setVisible(true);
                            imgPath = 4;
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            //f1.remove(p1);
                            p2.setVisible(false);
                            p2.removeAll();
                            ImageIcon icon3 = new ImageIcon("C:\\img7.png");
                            JLabel label3 = new JLabel(icon3);    
                            p2.add(label3);
                            p2.setVisible(true);
                            imgPath = 1;
                            break;
                    }                   
                    f1.add(p2);
                    f1.setVisible(true);
                    f1.setLayout(null);                 
                    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                }
                } catch (InterruptedException iex) {
                    System.out.println(iex);
                }           
            }

      }
     }
}

public class thdmkr extends Thread{

        Thread t1,t2;       
        subviewer1 obj1 = new subviewer1();
        subviewer2 obj2 = new subviewer2();     
        public thdmkr(){            
            //super();          
            t1 = new Thread(obj1);
            t2 = new Thread(obj2);
            t1.start();
            t2.start();         
        }

    public static void main(String args[]){     
        thdmkr obj = new thdmkr();      
    }

    public void run(){  

        }   
}
```

this is for different frames..but i want to be done it in single frame...so please correct my code or do a similar like code using *****Thread.sleep(int args);***** only

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Please use code formatting for code, input/output & structured documents like HTML or XML.  To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form. 3) Please use the correct spelling for words like 'you', 'your' & 'please'.  This makes it easier for people to understand and help.

Answer (score 5):

Swing is not thread safe. That is, you are required to only access, change or create UI elements from within a single thread, known as the Event Dispatching Thread (AKA EDT).

You should also never block the EDT, using things like `sleep`, `wait` or blocking IO for example

While there are a number of possible solutions to the problem, the simplest would be to use a `javax.swing.Timer`, as it executes its ticks within the context of the EDT, but won't block it while it waits.

Take a look at [Concurrency on Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details

I'd also recommend simply using a `JLabel` to display the icon and instead of adding and removing them, simply set the icon to the reference of the new image